# bootstrap how to make div appear above backdrop like a model

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a div which I want to highlight on click. Onclick, I use the bootstrap over the screen, but how do I make the div appear above the backdrop. I know using the modal is a easier solution. But I want to try this method.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried changing the z-index CSS value of the item you want on top? the higher the z-index value the more 'on-top' it will be.

Comment: @Gerton i have tried z-index:1 but does not seem to work

Comment: Like I said, the higher the z-index the more on top the item will be, 1 is usually the lowest. try setting it to another value like 30

Comment: z-index:1050 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Change z-index of your div in your CSS file to something like this:

```
z-index: 999;
```

See more details on how z-index works here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp